# Connection issue through embedded ethernet port on IC695CPE310-Axxx

Tags: networking, ip, plc, proficy, ladder-logic

I am unable to connect through the embedded ethernet port on the controller. Unable to ping the IP address. A ping sweep tool indicates the address is correct but with a slower then expected response time.

If I ping the IP from windows CMD it times out. If I use a sweep scan tool, “Angry IP Scanner”, it shows up but with a high ping response time, 1700 – 1900ms, typically I see this as 3 – 9ms. IGS Server is unable to connect. I am able to connect through COM1 RS-232 port.

Looking at the settings in PAC Machine Edition, it shows the IP and other TCP/IP settings. I have compared this to other RX3i systems on our network and everything seems consistent.

I connected through COM1 RS-232. And performed a system backup.

I originally thought this may be a hardware issue, so I found another CPE310, updated the firmware to the latest version v10.85. I restored the backup I had performed through COM1 connection. The system successfully restored, and everything functions as expected although the connection issue remains.

I feel like I am missing or overlooking something obvious on this. I have searched and read many threads and forums and and unable to find anything related to this issue. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried restoring the backup to another IC695CPE310-Axxx. I also tried changing the IP address. I have tried connecting to the PLC over the network and have tried connecting computer directly into PLC controller, changing my computers IP in IPV3 to match network.